# Writing my output into two columns in a text file .txt in C

Tags: c, output, text-files

I've looked around but couldn't find a satisfying solution... Basically I made a function that calculates the probability distribution of x number of loss in a portfolio of n credits... And I am trying to write the output in a text file into two columns where the first column would be the X (number of defaults) and second column would be the P(density function of each loss).. something like this:

```
X    P
1  0.005
2  0.003
3  0.005
4  0.005
5  0.005
```

etc.

I've looked around and people suggested using negative- sign in front of my %d and %f when using fprintf but no luck....

Here's a sample of my code and the output it gives me...
Code:

```
for(i=0;i<d+1;i++)
{
    Densite= gsl_ran_binomial_pdf(i,p,d);
    fprintf(pF,"%-5d %-20f .\n",i, Densite);

}
```

Output:
0     0.005921             .
1     0.031161             .
2     0.081182             .
3     0.139576             .
4     0.178143             .
5     0.180018             .
6     0.150015             .
7     0.106026             .
8     0.064871             .
9     0.034901             .
10    0.016716             .

How to remedy?

Thanks in advance! (complete noob that started coding in C like two days ago..)

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the executable program on Windows or Linux? If Window please use \r\n for new line.